# eBay Trading API: Problems getting user token pragmatically through FetchToken

Tags: xml, node.js, authentication, ebay-api

I am trying to authenticate a user for the eBay Trading API, but I am unable to generate a token 100% pragmatically. I have been able to generate the SessionID, but when I send an HTTP request to the FetchToken endpoint, I get the following error (in JSON):

```
{
  "FetchTokenResponse": {
    "$": {
      "xmlns": "urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents"
    },
    "Timestamp": [
      "2016-06-04T20:57:56.002Z"
    ],
    "Ack": [
      "Failure"
    ],
    "Errors": [
      {
        "ShortMessage": [
          "The end user has not completed Auth & Auth sign in flow."
        ],
        "LongMessage": [
          "The end user has not completed Auth & Auth sign in flow."
        ],
        "ErrorCode": [
          "21916017"
        ],
        "SeverityCode": [
          "Error"
        ],
        "ErrorClassification": [
          "RequestError"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "Version": [
      "949"
    ],
    "Build": [
      "E949_INTL_API_17934825_R1"
    ]
  }
}
```

The XML I am sending in my POST request is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\
<FetchTokenRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">\
  <SessionID>MY_GENERATED_SESSION_ID</SessionID>\
</FetchTokenRequest>
```

where the App ID, Dev ID, and the Cert ID are all in the HTTP headers. If it makes a difference, the link to the [code in a gist is here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/96171d023425f112f273bb9589dbe54d). How do I authenticate and generate a token for a user without having the user go to the login page mentioned in their documentation? If someone can point me in the right direction, I would sincerely appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the username in the request credentials. The xml structure should be like the one below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FetchTokenRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<RequesterCredentials>
<username>Ebay_Username_Of_User_Authentication</username>
</RequesterCredentials>
  <SessionID>Session_ID_Returned_by_ebay</SessionID>
</FetchTokenRequest>
```